# How can I find the maximum and minimum of $f(x,y)$ in $D=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2 \le 4 \}$?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

How can I find the maximum and minimum of $f(x,y)$ in $D=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2 \le 4 \}$

where 
$$f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-x^2-2xy-y^2$$

Answer:

$$f_x=4x^3-2x-2y$$
$$f_y=4y^3-2y-2x$$

Critical points are $(0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1)$.

All of these critical points are in D.

$$f(0,0)=0$$
$$f(1,1)=-2$$
$$f(-1,-1)=-2$$

Now we can find the extreme values of $f$ on the boundary of the region $x^2+y^2=4$

$$x^2=4-y^2$$

Therefore we have,
$$g(y)=2y^4-8y^2-2y \sqrt{4-y^2}+16$$

$$g'(y)=8y^3-16y-2 \sqrt{4-y^2}+2y^2(4-y^2)^{-1/2}=0$$

$\color{red}{problem:}$
I could do only up to here. I don't know how to solve the above equation to get the values for $y$.

After finding extreme values of this, we can compare those values with the above and we can find the maximum and minimum values.

Comment: will it be hopeful to translate the problem to the  polar coordinates?

Comment: Have you learned the method of Lagrange multipliers?  This would probably be an easier way to find critical points on the boundary circle.

Comment: Find the extreme values of g(y). $g(2)=g(-2) = 16$. $g'(y) = 0 \implies (4y^2-8)(2y\sqrt{4-y^2} - 1) = 0.$ Then it is now easy to find the critical points of g(y).

Comment: @corbah Thank you very much for the answer! I could solve the problem easily with this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to write the boundary as
$$x=2\cos\theta\ ,\quad y=2\sin\theta\ .$$
Then
$$\eqalign{f(x,y)
  &=16\cos^4\theta+16\sin^4\theta-4\cos^2\theta-8\cos\theta\sin\theta-4\sin^2\theta\cr
  &=4(1+\cos2\theta)^2+4(1-\cos2\theta)^2-4\sin2\theta-4\cr
  &=4+8\cos^22\theta-4\sin2\theta\cr
  &=12-4\sin2\theta-8\sin^22\theta\cr}$$
and it should not be hard to find extreme values of this.

Answer (score 0):

We have on the boundary $x^2+y^2=4$:

$$f=x^4+y^4-(x^2+y^2)-2xy=(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2-(x^2+y^2)-2xy=12-2((xy)^2+xy)$$

Note that $|xy| \leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}=2$, and the extremal values of $t \mapsto t^2+t$ for $|t| \leq 2$ are $6$ (for $t=2$) and $-\frac{1}{4}$ (for $t=-\frac{1}{2}$).

This shows

$$0 \leq f=12-2((xy)^2+xy) \leq \frac{25}{2}$$

and the values are admitted. $x=y=\pm \sqrt{2}$ yields $f=0$ and $f=\frac{25}{2}$ is admitted for the solutions of $xy=-\frac{1}{2}, x^2+y^2=4$: [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%3D-0.5,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%3D-0.5,%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4) (Of course you can compute the solutions by hand, but that is not my job :) )